# how to get list of selected nodes in angular ivh tree view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tree, treeview, treecontrol

I am new this ivh tree, https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview

I have been successfully able to configure this library, however I am not able to get the list of selected nodes, is there a way to get list of selected nodes programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `ivhTreeviewBfs` to collect selected nodes.

```
var selectedNodes = []
ivhTreeviewBfs(myTree, function(node) {
  if(node.selected) {
    selectedNodes.push(node)
  }
})
```

Note that you can use `ivhTreeviewOptions` to get the appropriate "selected" attribute if you want to be fully generic. Also, folks will often want to only collect the *top-most* selected node for a given tree branch. In this case you can return `false` in the callback passed to `ivhTreeviewBfs` and that node's children will not be visited.

You can read more about the bfs service [here](https://github.com/ivantage/angular-ivh-treeview#tree-traversal).

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have asked another question, id be great if you can help out there, stackoverflow.com/questions/39083564/